# Added " $ git add -" " can't go back

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I mistkanely typed $ git add -" and now instead of showning the "$" it shows a ">" and I can't go back.

I'm new to github and terminal in general.

Comment: Your question is irrelevant to all of the `git`, `github` and `visual-sudio-code` tags. You're dealing with a terminal and shell (most likely `bash`) and the question should be tagged accordingly. By inputting `"`" and `<Enter>`, your shell was suggesting you to complete the string literal you just started. And this is really irrelevant to `git` since Git wasn't even running at that moment, but to **any** shell input, say `echo "` would cause totally the same behavior.

Comment: 1) You could either complete the string by inputting the terminating `"` to complete the input. Shell `'`s have similar behavior. 2) You could abort your input by pressing `<Ctrl>+<C>` letting your shell to prompt you for another command input. 3) You could press `<Ctrl>+<D>` to emit the EOF mark to the current input therefore cancelling the command input by finishing with an unterminated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exiting your terminal and open it back up again.
You should be able to use the terminal normally.

Comment: @nanosphere11 -- I'm glad Exortions answer resolved your issue! Please remember to mark it as your selected correct answer by clicking the checkbox next to it, to both give credit to the answerer as well as indicate to later visitors to this post that the solution worked for you.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: also didn't know that haha thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Well... This is kind of an advice of demolishing a house just because you locked the door while having your master keys lost whilst the backed up keys are somewhere around you. Restaring the OS would technically result the same. Sorry. downvoted, since the answer didn't make any attempt to check what **really** went wrong (or "wrong").